# javascript replace url link loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, url, replace

I am a beginner for Javascript, read several post here but could not get my codes work. Hope you can explain the solution :)

So basically I have four set of images, but I need to replace all of the  `$_12.JPG`to `$_57.JPG` in their URL so I get bigger size of pictures (only images that are assigned to `class="ebay"` / `id="ebay"`). I need this to be executed when the browser starts reading the page, no events or buttons involved.

The following is my source code:

```
<div>
<img class="ebay" id="ebay" u="image" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/neAAAOSwrklU28I8/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F">
<img u="thumb" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/neAAAOSwrklU28I8/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F">
</div>
<div>
<img class="ebay" id="ebay" u="image" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/r8cAAOSwNSxU28I9/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F">
<img u="thumb" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/r8cAAOSwNSxU28I9/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F">
</div>
<div>
<img class="ebay" id="ebay" u="image" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/HLgAAOSwPhdU28I-/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F">
<img u="thumb" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/HLgAAOSwPhdU28I-/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F">
</div>
<div>
<img class="ebay" id="ebay" u="image" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/6VkAAOSwPYZU28I-/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F">
<img u="thumb" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/6VkAAOSwPYZU28I-/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F">
</div>
```

I also like to loop the function so when I have more than 4 sets of pictures (maximum 15 sets) and the javascript can still replace the URL for me.

The following is what I had tried:

```
window.onload = function() {

    for ( var i = 0; i < currentLink.length; i++) {

    var currentLink=document.getElementByClassName('ebay');
    var newLink = currentLink.src.replace('$_12.JPG','$_57.JPG');
    currentLink.src = newLink;

    }
}
```

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar No, it doesn't, it returns (when correctly written) a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is an object.

Comment: Note that technically speaking, `window.onload` IS an event... actually you seem quite close to the solution...

Comment: @Teemu Isn't HTMLCollection is a collection of elements..so to say Array?

Comment: It's not an array, the said object doesn't have methods like `push`or `pop` etc.

Comment: @Teemu Well if its an object.. how does it supports `length` property?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar Because that property is built in that object ; ). Please read the documentation I've linked above, there's just one property and two methods introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misplacement of `var currentLink=document.getElementByClassName('ebay');`

Do,

```
window.onload = function() {

    var currentLink=document.getElementsByClassName('ebay');
    for ( var i = 0; i < currentLink.length; i++) { 
    var newLink = currentLink[i].src.replace('$_12.JPG','$_57.JPG');
    currentLink[i].src = newLink;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will give error....As you have done typo mistake `getElementByClassName` instead of `getElementsByClassName`..

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize that `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a single element. So you cannot simply change all the elements in the collection by accessing the `.src` property of the collection.

You need to iterate over the collection to do this:

```
var currentLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('ebay');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(currentLinks, function(currentLink) {
    var newLink = currentLink.src.replace('$_12.JPG','$_57.JPG');
    currentLink.src = newLink;
});
```

Also, you have a typo in your `getElementByClassName` (you're missing the `s` in `Elements`).

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)